# apache htaccess codeigniter query string to path

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, path

i'm trying to make a codeigniter based website be able to convert index.php?option=test&controller=con1 to /test/con1 using .htaccess i tried multiple examples i found and none seem to work, it goes straight to the home page. any ideas?

i've tried things like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/?   /index.php/$1/$2 [L]
```

but doesn't throw any errors or anything. 
 my current htacces is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|img|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try put this .htaccess in same directory with your index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: moving one of the rewritecond to a different spot?

Comment: just try to replace your current htaccess with i provided above

Comment: OK I did and see no difference, still ignoring the GET parameters.